proc sql with do loop joining info from two tables in SAS
Looking to do something like this more efficiently:
proc sql;
create table newtable as
select names, 
a.category1-b.category1 as category1,
a.category2-b.category2 as category2,
a.category3-b.category3 as category3,
...
a.category100-b.category100 as category100
from a.tablea as a left join b.tableb as b
on a.names=b.names;
quit;

I'm trying to create just one table and decrease the amount of lines I take up in my code.  Figured that macro do loops may help, but not sure how.  Please help!  Thank you!!
%macro doloop;
%do from i=1 %to 100;
proc sql;
create table newtable as
select names, 
a.category&i.-b.category&i. as category&i
from tablea as a left join tableb as b
on a.names=b.names;
quit;
%end;
%mend;
%doloop;

I get this error: 'ERROR: FROMI is an invalid macro variable name for the index variable of the %do loop.'

Why SQL?  Can't you do this in a data step?  Are the datasets sorted by NAMES already? Are you doing just a one to one (or one to many) merge?  If so you can use a data step instead.

do i=1 to 10;   There is no "do from" command in SAS.

Your %DO statement syntax is invalid.
Your %DO loop placement is incorrect.
%macro doloop;
%local i;
proc sql;
create table newtable as
  select names
%do i=1 %to 100;
  , a.category&i.-b.category&i. as category&i
%end;
  from tablea as a left join tableb as b
    on a.names=b.names
;
quit;
%mend;
%doloop;

